# Create a wifi hotspot in a place where an authentication is required

Tags: wireless-networking

I live in a residence where Internet is provided via cable. Once the computer is connected to the cable, launching a browser will trigger an authentication, I have a username and password to enter, then the internet will be connected.

[image]

With a gateway (e.g. [Wireless Cable Voice 
Gateway Model CBVG834G](http://sidoine.pierrel.net/data/CBVG834G_AdminUM_8Feb08.pdf)) and 2 cables, two PCs can connect to the Internet with my account at the same time.

Now the question is, I don't like the cable, and would like to create a wifi hotspot. It seems realizable with the same gateway. According to the instruction on page 2-4 of the [manual](http://sidoine.pierrel.net/data/CBVG834G_AdminUM_8Feb08.pdf): `Enter http://192.168.0.1 in the address field of your Internet browser. Log in to the gateway 
with either of the default user names, MSO or admin...` However, while connecting to the Internet successfully via cable and the gateway (e.g. google works), opening `192.168.0.1` oddly gives me an error on the browser:

[image]

Does anyone know what happened? Is it due to the authentication required by my residence? Is there any other way to build a hotspot of wifi?

PS: My system is MAC OS

Comment: Is you device actually at 192.168.0.1?  How about you edit your question to include the actual networking configurations you're using, and the actual error message(s) you're seeing?  Also, have you checked with the school to ensure you are allowed to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "is your device actually at 192.168.0.1"? I have added the error message to OP. I haven't checked with the manager of my residence, because having Internet here is already a luxe in their view...

Comment: what techie007 means is the following, check what it is actually you gateway when you're connecting via ethernet, then try configuring the router with the gateway that ethernet uses, [here](http://kb.iu.edu/data/ajfx.html) you can check how to know your gateway

Comment: Run `ifconfig -a` in a terminal and show us the output. (text is fine, no need for a screenshot)

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? Your Internet access is provided by a local cable company through a cable modem, and you want to replace the cable modem with your Netgear CBVG834G. You have connected the CBVG834G to the cable outlet in the wall as explained in page 1-5 and you can access www.google.com when your computer is plugged into the Ethernet port of the CBVG834G, but you can't access http://192.168.0.1. Can you confirm this? Can you provide a screenshot of System Preferences>Network (please select "Ethernet" in the left panel before making the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You can have your hotspot, but you can't do it with an off-the-shelf hotspot devices. Such devices eliminate the keyboard/video/mouse of a PC, and you need that user interaction in order to log into your residence network.

Find a cheap used laptop (not a lot of space or power) with a Wifi adapter. Connect it your network, login, enable internet connection sharing, and close the lid. There's your hotspot,

This page might e helpful:

http://www.practicallynetworked.com/sharing/sharing.htm

Answer (score -1):

Your trouble is opening up the router control panel. Google Chrome will not open local host ip like 192.168.0.1

It will on Mozilla Firefox. I have not tried any other browsers.

I have a similar setup but with 2 laptops. And since my gateway does not support wifi hotspot I have to connect one of the laptops via a cable and create a hotspot on it using [connectify](http://www.connectify.me/). Then connect to the wifi using the other laptop [basically allowing freedom of movement in atleast one of the devices]

If you are sure your gateway supports wifi hotspot, try with a different browser.

I hope this gives you an idea and help you out.

Comment: Why do you say Chrome will not open a local host ip?

Comment: It has happened to me. Maybe it is related to a specific version of chrome or something.